# Using mouse wheel to scroll in Sencha Touch application on desktop

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

While looking for how to enable scrolling with the mouse wheel in Sencha Touch, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397159/adding-mousewheel-to-sencha-desktop-app) answer. However, I am relatively new to Sencha Touch and the codebase I was given to maintain that uses it.

The answer says to put it in the *initialization block of my application*: as far as I can tell, that would be my `app.js` file that is generated by Sencha Cmd (which has a `launch` function). However, I'm lost after this. Would I add the first part of the above answer *in* the `launch` block? Outside of it? How would I make sure that it is automatically called on every page?

**Edit**: Here is my `app.js` file, in case it helps.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.direct.*'
    ],

    models:[
        "..."
    ],

    controllers: [
        '...',
        '...',
        '...'
    ],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    profiles: ['Tablet', 'Phone'],

    launch: function() {

        ...
    }

    ....

});
```

**Edit 2**: I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.

Comment: I moved your solution to a Community wiki answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided code in the other answer is pure Javascript and not ExtJs code, it runs in a global scope so you can add this above Ext.application (outside of ExtJs code, so make it your first bit of JS code that gets run). You could even wrap it inside an Ext.onReady call to make sure ExtJs is also fully loaded before you add it, if needed.

This should work, it might be worth looking over the Sencha forums or even on here for a more elegant and updated solution though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that I think about it as you have portrayed, it makes quite a lot of sense. I'll try to look for a more maintainable solution to this, but for now this should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's answer above works, however it throws errors if trying to scroll over elements that do not have indexOf on their className (like SVG elements). Here is the updated code that first checks for the existence of indexOf.

I've also extended this method to support horizontal mouse scrolling if the browser supports wheelDeltaX and wheelDeltaY. Otherwise it defaults to using the more widely available wheelDelta and only scrolls in the Y direction.

Note that you can embed this code in a function and simply call it during the launch of your app. No need to put it at the top of the app.js file.

```html
        var mouseWheelHandler = function (e) {
            var e = window.event || e,
                el = e.target,
                cmp,
                offset,
                scroller,
                deltaY,
                deltaX,
                _results = [];
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent scrolling when in iframe
            while (el !== document.body) {
                if (el && el.className && el.className.indexOf && el.className.indexOf('x-container') >= 0) {
                    cmp = Ext.getCmp(el.id);
                    if (cmp && typeof cmp.getScrollable == 'function' && cmp.getScrollable()) {
                        scroller = cmp.getScrollable().getScroller();

                        if (scroller) {
                            deltaY = e.detail ? e.detail * (-120) : e.hasOwnProperty('wheelDeltaY') ? e.wheelDeltaY : e.wheelDelta;
                            deltaX = e.detail ? e.detail * (-120) : e.hasOwnProperty('wheelDeltaX') ? e.wheelDeltaX : 0; 
                            offset = {x: -deltaX * 0.5, y: -deltaY * 0.5};
                            scroller.fireEvent('scrollstart', scroller, scroller.position.x, scroller.position.y, e);
                            scroller.scrollBy(offset.x, offset.y);
                            scroller.snapToBoundary();
                            scroller.fireEvent('scrollend', scroller, scroller.position.x + offset.x, scroller.position.y - offset.y);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _results.push(el = el.parentNode);
            }
            return _results;
        };

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            document.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheelHandler, false);
            // Firefox
            document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelHandler, false);
        }
        else {
            // IE 6/7/8
            document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', mouseWheelHandler);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user991710 and Scriptable for your  answer. In my case i added the entire code within the Ext.onReady  event because it didn't work in the app.js.

Below is how i have incorporated the code in the Ext.onReady in the default.js

```
      onReady: function() {
        if (this.getAutoRender()) {
            this.render();
        }
        if (Ext.browser.name == 'ChromeiOS') {
            this.setHeight('-webkit-calc(100% - ' + ((window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) / 2) + 'px)');
        }

        /* code ten behoeve van mousescroll in Chrome situatie */
        var mouseWheelHandler = function (e) {
            var e = window.event || e,
el = e.target,
cmp,
offset,
scroller,
delta,
_results = [];
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent scrolling when in iframe
            while (el !== document.body) {
                if (el && el.className && el.className.indexOf('x-container') >= 0) {
                    cmp = Ext.getCmp(el.id);
                    if (cmp && typeof cmp.getScrollable == 'function' && cmp.getScrollable()) {
                        scroller = cmp.getScrollable().getScroller();
                        if (scroller) {
                            delta = e.detail ? e.detail * (-120) : e.wheelDelta;
                            offset = { x: 0, y: -delta * 0.5 };
                            scroller.fireEvent('scrollstart', scroller, scroller.position.x, scroller.position.y, e);
                            scroller.scrollBy(offset.x, offset.y);
                            scroller.snapToBoundary();
                            scroller.fireEvent('scrollend', scroller, scroller.position.x, scroller.position.y - offset.y);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _results.push(el = el.parentNode);
            }
            return _results;
        };

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            document.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheelHandler, false);
            // Firefox
            document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelHandler, false);
        }
        else {
            // IE 6/7/8
            document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', mouseWheelHandler);
        }
        /*einde code ten behoeve van muisscroll in Chrome modus */
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

In my `app.js` file (the one generated by Sencha Cmd), I added the following code at the very top of the file, *before* my `Ext.application` definition:

```
var mouseWheelHandler = function (e) {
    var e = window.event || e,
        el = e.target,
        cmp,
        offset,
        scroller,
        delta,
        _results = [];
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent scrolling when in iframe
    while (el !== document.body) {
        if (el && el.className && el.className.indexOf('x-container') >= 0) {
            cmp = Ext.getCmp(el.id);
            if (cmp && typeof cmp.getScrollable == 'function' && cmp.getScrollable()) {
                scroller = cmp.getScrollable().getScroller();
                if (scroller) {
                    delta = e.detail ? e.detail*(-120) : e.wheelDelta;
                    offset = { x:0, y: -delta*0.5 };
                    scroller.fireEvent('scrollstart', scroller, scroller.position.x, scroller.position.y, e);
                    scroller.scrollBy(offset.x, offset.y);
                    scroller.snapToBoundary();
                    scroller.fireEvent('scrollend', scroller, scroller.position.x, scroller.position.y-offset.y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    _results.push(el = el.parentNode);
    }
    return _results;
};

if (document.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheelHandler, false);
    // Firefox
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelHandler, false);
}
```

Credit to the above code goes to user [m.dostal](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?110792-Add-support-for-mouse-scrolling-(for-development)&p=1054413&viewfull=1#post1054413) on the Sencha Touch forums. If you happen across this solution, please upvote user Scriptable below as he helped me find the correct solution.